# Regex update in C#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

This regex pattern is not finding PageName correctly when pagename contains `-` like `PAGE-NAME=HomePage-Left-Of-Calendar` but it works when `PAGE-NAME=HomePage` can anyone help me to update this regex to support both...

```
var result = " <div id=\"header-left\" style=\"border:none\">";
result += "<!-- CMS-PAGE PAGE-NAME=HomePage-Left-Of-Calendar -->";
result += " </div>";

var pattern = @"(<!--)(\s*)(CMS-PAGE)(\s*)((PAGE-NAME)(=)(?<value>\w*)(\s*))*(\s*)(-->)";
var replaceTag = " <widget:ContentPageView runat=\"server\" PageName=\"@@value\" Editable=\"True\">" +
    "<DescriptionTemplate>...</DescriptionTemplate>" +
    "</widget:ContentPageView>";

result = RegexReplaceWithUniqueTag(result, pattern, replaceTag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a specific part of your regular expression:

```
(?<value>\w*)
```

This is matching only word characters (that's what `\w` means); however, you're also asking it to match non-word characters (specifically, the hyphen). Change this to:

```
(?<value>(\w|-)*)
```

and you will match both `HomePage` and `HomePage-Left-Of-Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the hyphen (`-`) in ordered to be matched.

You can simply place both `\w` and `-` inside of a character class `[]` together which will match any character of word characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`) and the literal character `-`

```
(?<value>[\w-]*)
```

Comment: I run both Adrian & your code both works fine .... whats the difference between both codes?

Comment: Both are valid for a simple case like this.